# How can I delete the top row of my csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

My code extracts information from an xhtml file to csv. Cannot seem to delete the topmost row reading "NYSE,, ,Price,Chg,Chg". Using "del data[0]" for example gets rid of the whole column. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
import re
import xml.dom.minidom

document = xml.dom.minidom.parse("2017-11-27-16-20-15.xhtml")
tableElements = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[2]

for tr in tableElements.getElementsByTagName('tr'):
data = []

for a in tr.getElementsByTagName('a'):
    for node in a.childNodes:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            data.append(node.nodeValue)


for td in tr.getElementsByTagName('td'):
    for node in td.childNodes:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            data.append(node.nodeValue)

del data[-1]
del data[1]
del data[1]
del data[1]

symbol = data[0]
symm = re.findall(r"\(([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\)", symbol)

sym = (''.join(symm))

company = data[0]
comp = re.sub("\(.*\)\n","", company)

volume = data[1]
lst = volume.replace(',', '')


price = data[2]
lstt = price.lstrip('$')


change = data[-1]

fullList = [sym] + [comp] + [lst] + [lstt] + [change]
fullList.insert(0, "NYSE")
print(','.join(fullList))
```

[output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5UQQ.png)

[xhtml table(sample pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4kV7.png)

Comment: Row or column? You first talk about row, then about column ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner what OP is saying is that he wants to remove the first row but his line is removing the first column.

Comment: @PatrickArtner i want to delete the first row that reads, ""NYSE,, ,Price,Chg,Chg"". (see link for pic). im just stating that when using del data[0] it rids of the entire column as opposed to that first row, if that makes sense

Comment: please post a `print(fullList[1:10])'

Comment: No clue - retracted my answer as not helpfull. Maybe post part of the table inside the xhtml and someone might chime in. Luck to you.

Comment: thank you anyway @PatrickArtner. I have just posted a sample of the xhtml file

Answer (score 0):

if data[0] return the whole column, then loop though you columns and delete the first entry.

```
for column in range(len(data)):
  del data[column][0]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion